# How to stop this rewrite rule throwing a 500 error if the image doesn't exist

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've set up this rule so handle not found images

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^files/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([^.]*).(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp) /open/img/404/$1.jpg [NC,L]
```

So if the url is `/files/offers/this/that/other/file.jpg`, and the image doesn't exists, it will display the image `/open/img/404/offers.jpg`. This works great and well, unless `offers.jpg` doesn't exist, then it throws a **500 Internal Server Error**.

Is it possible to make the rule only return the `/open/img/404/something.jpg` image if it is there, if not return `/open/img/404/defaultImage.jpg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you can have rules like this:

```
# if /open/img/404/$1.jpg exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/open/img/404/$1.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^files/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([^.]+)\.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp) /open/img/404/$1.jpg [NC,L]

# if /open/img/404/$1.jpg doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/open/img/404/$1.jpg !-f
RewriteRule ^files/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([^.]+)\.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp) /open/img/404/defaultImage.jpg [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks :), That works great. Just curious, on the 2nd and 4th RewriteCond, where does the $1 param come from? From the Rule below it?

Comment: Yes that is true, `$1` comes from `RewriteRule`